# SOQL_SOSL Injection

Tags: apex, community

I got the SOQL injection error 4 times for the same code block when i tried to upload my managed package.

```
public void fetchListviewRecords() {  

    columnName = new List<String>();
    fields = new List<String>();
    parserCol =  new List<listviewAPI.Columns>();
    recordList = new List<sObject>();
    allRecords = new List<List<sObject>>();
    try{
        String listid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('listid');
        String ObjectName = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Object');
        String listName = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('listName');
        fileName =  ObjectName +'_'+listName.replace(' ','_') +'_'+ Datetime.now().format();
        //Http callout 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        String domainUrl=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        system.debug('********domainUrl:'+domainUrl);
        String endpointUrl = domainUrl+'/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/' +(ObjectName=='Person_Account'?'Account':ObjectName)+'/listviews/'+listid+'/describe';
        system.debug('domain URL' + endpointUrl);
        req.setEndpoint(endpointUrl);
        req.setMethod('GET');      
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Map<String,Object> root  = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());     
        //Nested list logic to overcome collection limit
        for(Sobject sobj : Database.query((string)root.get('query')))
```

Could anyone help me in fixing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include any specific details about the error?

Comment: Have you mocked the HttpResponse for the REST list views in your test cases? It won't be possible to make the actual callout during testing, which also occurs during packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was flagged as vulnerable to SOQL injection because it takes a response received from the Web and passes it into a SOQL query with no escaping or validation.

Now the response is coming from Salesforce, but that's not enough. The result of this query should be viewed using the /results param in listview REST calls or directly as a query in the REST API, and not passed into a SOQL query in Apex. This is because the REST API is safe -- it always performs CRUD/FLS checks and enforces sharing, whereas Apex runs in system mode and you need to do the isAccessible() checks yourself. You can't do that if you don't know all the fields, and you can't know the fields if the query is opaque to you. That is really what SOQL injection is about: it's a special case of CRUD/FLS bypass in which an attacker sneaks in other SOQL structure that you cannot perform an isAccessible check on.

Moreover there is no documented contract in the listview API that guarantees that any SOQL query returned will be safe to call in system mode Apex without any additional CRUD checks. So don't do it.

*Nevertheless* as currently implemented, it's safe! The listview will not be returned if any of the fields or where clauses in the view are ones that the current user can't access *even though* the current user will see the list view in visualforce.

Here is an example:

1. Create an object with two fields, "public" and "private".
2. Give global access to public but give access to the private__c field only to the sysadmin profile.
3. create a listview, A,  that shows all the fields. Be sure to grant access to the object to the standard user.

Now, the standard user can see this listview in the UI, but when he runs the view, the private field will be missing from the results.

4. Create another listview, B, which uses a WHERE clause on the private field.

The standard user will not be able to see this listview at all in the UI.

All of the above should make sense, in terms of controlling information flow.

Now turn to the API. The standard user will not be able to receive either A or B via the REST API, even though he can use listview A in the UI.

This additional *undocumented* level of filtering is what makes this a false positive.

However, you still may fail the security review, because you are relying on undocumented behavior and engaging in a bad practice:

*Only execute in Apex those queries that you can unambiguously parse.*

Because the security review is a point in time review, we care more about your knowledge and adherence to secure coding guidelines than about ensuring a given snapshot of the code is vulnerability free.

At the end of the day you will only be able to safeguard your users' data if you program defensively and stay well clear of edge cases. Moreover, as a practical matter, if you rely on undocumented behavior, no one is going to have time to run a full test matrix to verify your claim. You need to be able to point to something in the official developer guide (not on a blog) in order to claim a certain security behavior.

Strings that you cannot parse should never be used within Apex queries, but should be used within REST queries. Similarly, do not eval() or apply innerHTML() to strings that you cannot parse and validate either. You are responsible for validating everything that your code renders, this is not something you can offload to any other service -- including Salesforce.

Also, please make sure that this method is running within a class that is 'with sharing' and avoid the SOQL queries within for loops.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the suggestion. I will make the needed changes.

Answer (score 1):

Before setting the endPointURL and callout, Can you make sure that

- listid is of type Id and max of 18 characters and minimum of 15 characters before adding it to endpoint. You can try using Id.valueOf(listId) This will throw invalid Id Exception if listId is of not type "Id"
- ObjectName contains only 1 object and it is an existing object in your salesforce Org. Can use Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName) != null

Example:
if(listId of type 'Id' and ObjectName is an existing salesforce Org Object) {
//Http callout
}